# Getting "hello" from "1. hello" with Regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am just learning regex and I am having trouble with getting the word from a list

From a list like:

```
[ "1. hello - jeff", "2. gello - meff", "3. fellow - gef", "12. willow - left"]
```

I want retrieve the words: "hello", "gello", "fellow", and "willow"

Here is my simplified code so far

```
for i in [ARRAY OF LISTED WORDS]:
  word = re.findall(r'^((?![0-9]?[0-9]. ))\w+', i)
  print(word)
```

Comment: @ggorlen I have tried r"\w+", I only got the number: "1.", "2.", "3." etc. Your second suggestion got me the same thing. I hope I did it right.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I still don't see how "\w+" will skip over: a numeric value, a period, and space in the string "1. hello" to only capture "hello."

Comment: Yeah, as I commented (and removed once requirements changed) `\w+` gives you a list of all words using `findall`. You can take the last or middle item in the list `findall` returns. The point is to show that there are many ways to achieve the result and it's unclear why some might be better than others absent more information. Is it possible some items won't be in the shown format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for one or more *non-spaces* (`'\S+'`) between digits followed by a period followed by a space (`'\d+\.\s'`), and a space followed by a dash (`'\s-'`):

```
pattern = r'\d+\.\s(\S+)\s-'
[re.findall(pattern, l)[0] for l in your_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern:

```
pattern = r"""
    \d+     # 1 or more digits
    \.      # Escaped period character
    \s+?    # 1 or more whitespace
    (\w+)   # 1 or more alphabetic characters
    \s+     # 1 or more whitespace
    -       # hyphen
    .*      # zero or more of anything besides newline.
"""
```

list of strings:

```
words = [ "1. hello - jeff", "2. gello - meff", "3. fellow - gef", "12. willow - left"]


for word in words:
    # capture results in a variable
    # re.X for verbose pattern format.
    tmp = re.search(pattern, word, flags = re.X)
    # If variable is not None, print results of the first captured group.
    if tmp:
        print(tmp.group(1))
```

Output:

```
hello
gello
fellow
willow
```